# SQL date comparison in WHERE clause, TypoScript

Tags: sql, date, typo3, where-clause, typoscript

I want to compare dates in a TypoScript select.
Here's what I have (note that I commented the **were** clauses) :

```
lib.my_val = CONTENT
lib.my_val {
  select {
    pidInList = 100000
    max = 1
    #where = effective_date < CURDATE()
    #where = TIMESTAMP(effective_date) < NOW()
    orderBy = effective_date DESC
  }
  table = tx_my_table
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    5 = TEXT
    5{
      field = my_field
      wrap = <span>|</span>
    }
    [...]
  }
}
```

Which returns lines.

I tried to add a **where** statement any way I could with static dates or variables... without success. My understanding of the **where** clause is that everything after the `=` is dumped *as is* in the SQL query. But it seems I missed something.

Basically I want the TypoScript to generate a SQL Query smilar to this :

`SELECT * FROM tx_my_table WHERE effective_date < NOW() ORDER BY effective_date DESC LIMIT 1;`

This should be simple. Has anyone done this in the past?

Thanks!

Comment: What format is effective_date? I assume it's datetime `YYYY-MM-DD`, not timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TypoScript seems to be OK.

- What happens if you enter the SQL Query directly into MySQL?
- Note that with your code, only one record with `pid=100000` is
  selected.
- Have you tried this:

--

```
lib.my_val {  
       select {  
        pidInList = 100000  
        max = 1  
        where = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(effective_date) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()  
        orderBy = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(effective_date) DESC  
      }  
      table = tx_my_table  
    }
```

[TYPO3 Wiki on select](http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/select)

Comment: UNIX_TIMESTAMP() did it. I'm in an environment where I don't have access to the DB, but I think the date is stored as an INT... Oh that's what I missed. Thanks.